# Hide mouse after inactivity with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, mouse

How would you go about hiding the mouse after  seconds of inactivity with Qt?

I know to hide the mouse you can `setCursor(Qt::BlankCursor);`, but how would I make it hide after inactivity, and reappear again when it is moved?

Comment: Use a [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html)?

Comment: @G.M. How would I do that? Could you perhaps link me to an example? Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever used `QTimer`? If not, please find a tutorial on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

QMouseHider.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <atomic>

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTimer>


class QMouseHider : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    using DurationT = int /* Or "std::chrono::milliseconds" */;

    static inline QMouseHider& Instance()
    {
        static QMouseHider i;
        return i;
    }

    explicit inline QMouseHider() : _InactivityDuration{DurationT{}}
    {
        QCoreApplication::instance()->installEventFilter(this);

        _Timer.setSingleShot(true);
        _Timer.callOnTimeout(
            [this]() {
                ControlCursor(false);
            }
        );
    }

    // [in] InactivityDuration: In milliseconds
    //
    inline void SetInactivityDuration(DurationT Value)
    {
        _InactivityDuration = Value;
    }

private:
    std::atomic<DurationT> _InactivityDuration; // In msec
    QTimer _Timer;

    inline bool eventFilter(QObject *pWatched, QEvent *pEvent) override
    {
        if (pEvent->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
        {
            ControlCursor(true);

            if (_InactivityDuration != DurationT{}) {
                _Timer.start(_InactivityDuration);
            }
        }

        return QObject::eventFilter(pWatched, pEvent);
    }

    inline void ControlCursor(bool Show)
    {
        QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Show ? Qt::ArrowCursor : Qt::BlankCursor);
    }

};
```

Usage:

```
#include "QtTest.h"

#include "QMouseHider.hpp"


QtTest::QtTest(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    auto& MouseHider = QMouseHider::Instance();

    // Set the inactivity duration
    //
    MouseHider.SetInactivityDuration(2000);
}
```